# How do I change Spinnaker configs after an installation with helm?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-pubsub, hal, spinnaker

I'm new to using Spinnaker and Halyard. I'm following this guide by [Google](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-kubernetes-engine#start_a_cloud_shell_instance).

When installing Spinnaker, they use `helm` and attach on a `spinnaker-config.yaml` file that looks like this:

```
./helm install -n cd stable/spinnaker -f spinnaker-config.yaml --timeout 600 \
    --version 1.1.6 --wait
```

`spinnaker-config.yaml`:

```
export SA_JSON=$(cat spinnaker-sa.json)
export PROJECT=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.project)')
export BUCKET=$PROJECT-spinnaker-config
cat > spinnaker-config.yaml <<EOF
gcs:
  enabled: true
  bucket: $BUCKET
  project: $PROJECT
  jsonKey: '$SA_JSON'

dockerRegistries:
- name: gcr
  address: https://gcr.io
  username: _json_key
  password: '$SA_JSON'
  email: 1234@5678.com

# Disable minio as the default storage backend
minio:
  enabled: false

# Configure Spinnaker to enable GCP services
halyard:
  spinnakerVersion: 1.10.2
  image:
    tag: 1.12.0
  additionalScripts:
    create: true
    data:
      enable_gcs_artifacts.sh: |-
        \$HAL_COMMAND config artifact gcs account add gcs-$PROJECT --json-path /opt/gcs/key.json
        \$HAL_COMMAND config artifact gcs enable
      enable_pubsub_triggers.sh: |-
        \$HAL_COMMAND config pubsub google enable
        \$HAL_COMMAND config pubsub google subscription add gcr-triggers \
          --subscription-name gcr-triggers \
          --json-path /opt/gcs/key.json \
          --project [project_guid] \
          --message-format GCR
EOF
```

I need to add another `pubsub` with a different name than `gcr-triggers` and noticed that anything I try to add in a pipeline won't persist. I suspect this is because it needs to be added with `hal` like so:

*note: I've already created and verified `gcloud` `subscriptions` and `add-iam-policy-binding`.*

```
hal config pubsub google subscription add [new_trigger] \
          --subscription-name [new_trigger] \
          --json-path /opt/gcs/key.json \
          --project $PROJECT \
          --message-format GCR
```

I suspect installing `spinnaker` like so is kind of unconventional (correct me if I'm wrong). I've never ran a `hal` binary from my master machine where `kubectl` is run and this was not necessary in the guide. Spinnaker's [architecture](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/architecture/) has a bunch of pods I can see. I've poked around in them and didn't see `hal`.

**My question is: with this guide, how am I suppose to `hal config` new things? What's the normal way this is done?**

Answer (score 0):

Helm is a package manager similar to apt in some linux distros.
Because this is a Micro service Architecture running in Kubernetes you must access the Halyard Pod (actually it should be a stateful set)

- Get Halyard Pod 
  `export HALYARD=$(kubectl -n spinnaker get pod -l app=halyard -oname | cut -d'/' -f 2)`
- Access Halyard Pod in Spinnaker namespace `kubectl -n spinnaker exec -it ${HALYARD} /bin/bash`
- Test access by running the command `hal config` you should get the full config of spinnaker
- After you apply the changes you need dont forget to use `hal deploy apply`